# Change Vertical Spacing of CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Am using UICollectionView and changing the size of the item in the delegate method of collection view like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    lastIndex = 0;
    layoutDiff = 4;
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == (lastIndex + layoutDiff) - 1){
        layoutDiff = (layoutDiff == 4)?5:4;
        lastIndex = indexPath.row + 1;
        return CGSizeMake(213.2, 213.2);
    }

    return CGSizeMake(106.6, 106.6);
}
```

and here is my current screen.

[image]

and all the below cells to be follow this behaviour, means the pattern i want is like one collection view item to big depending on my logic where i want to make it big but i don't want this space. I think if the space will not b there then all things will be right. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlowLayout can't help with this.

You hava to implement your subclass of UICollectionLayout.

Here are some articles that take about custom Collection View Layout.

Custom Collection View Layouts.

https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/

Knowing When to Subclass the Flow Layout
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW4

Comment: i have tried the urls and i have created custom layout for my requirement and i have assigned values. now am stuck at the first function in which i need to get the indexPathsOfItemsInRect. i could not figure it out. but thanks for the reference urls. am working on them.

Comment: If you feel  my answer  is helpful... Adopt It.. Thank you.

Comment: actually i have my correct calculation and this helped me a lot. https://github.com/ra1028/RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout  

i have just replaced the frame changing code with my logic and the collection view content size changing logic with my code. thank you pointing me in the right direction.